# Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 Fails to Install on Lexar 500GB NM610 M.2 NVMe SSD

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, ssd, windows-10

I very recently bought [a computer](https://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?cPath=1446_1448&item_id=190647&sid=fn1t5tche54hm7k3us2d9h6rg0) with the followings specs:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core
- GPU: GeForce RTX 3060
- SSD: Lexar 500GB NM610 M.2 NVMe SSD
- RAM: 2 HyperX Fury DDR4 8 GB RAM = 16 GB RAM in total
- Motherboard: Gigabyte Technology, A520M DS3H AC
- OS: Windows 10 Home
- BIOS Mode (under System information): UEFI

I am trying to install an Ubuntu (preferably version 18.04) dual boot alongside windows 10. I have tried installing both Ubuntu 18.04, and 20.04. When I try installing 20.04, I get the same error as the person [in this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/izjzy0/the_ext4_file_system_creation_in_partition_2_of/) who has the **exact same SSD as me**. As they state in their reddit thread, they tried many different things but ultimately were only able to successfully install Ubuntu once they got a different SSD. I have followed [this tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/) as well as [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-20-04-lts-in-a-few-hassle-free-steps-f0e465c3aafd).

Here is a picture of the error I get when following the second tutorial I mentioned (for Ubuntu 20.04):
[image]

Here is a picture of the error I get when choosing to install using "install alongside windows" instead of "something else" (for Ubuntu 20.04, without partitioning the SSD ahead of time in Windows):
[image]

Here is a picture of the error I get when following the first tutorial I mentioned (for Ubuntu 18.04):[image]

Here is a picture of what happens when choosing to install using "install alongside windows" instead of "something else". The progress bar on the install process gets stuck here, I waited for many hours, the cmd prompt keeps showing new text but I imagine it is in some sort of loop (for Ubuntu 18.04, I partitioned the SSD ahead of time in Windows):
[image]

Additionally, I always get this screen when booting from the USB (for both 18.04 and 20.04):
[image]

Is there some sort of 'systematic' way of debugging/figuring out what is happening? I have a feeling there is some sort of incompatibility with my SSD, but am not sure. Would an install be easier if I bought a second SSD, and installed Ubuntu on that SSD (so I then have a dual boot with one OS on each SSD). I've tried many different installs, the pictures here are not everything I have tried.

**Update 1:** I called Lexar support, and they said that Linux commonly has compatibility issues with their SSDs. This makes a lot of sense given the reddit post I linked in my question... I was able to get Ubuntu 21.04 to work with my SSD. That is not the version I want though... so I will likely get a different SSD that is compatible with Ubuntu 18.04. Any suggestions?

**Update 2:** Although Lexar doesn't have firmware updates for its SSDs, I was able to update my motherboard UEFI. I tried installing Ubuntu 18.04 again, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have a NVMe SSD, not a hard drive. Besides that only two comments to start troubleshooting: (1) When dual-booting with Windows, disabling it's Fast Startup feature is a must. So start with that and also use Windows' tools to shrink partitions to make room (unallocated space) for Ubuntu. (2) Some SSDs need firmware updates and UEFI itself often does even in new systems.

Comment: Many have needed firmware updates for both UEFI & SSD. But since newer hardware, you probably need 21.04 to have newest kernel & drivers.

Comment: @ChanganAuto ah yes, my apologies. I know I have a SSD, I referred to it as a hard drive by mistake. To restart, I hold down shift while clicking 'restart'. This disables fast start up as far as I know. I also have been using Windows' disk management tool to shrink partitions (it is specified in the tutorials I linked).

Comment: @ChanganAuto by 'update my UEFI' do you mean update my bios? as seen in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJGg2Gz7RIk. I bought my computer a few weeks ago, I'd be surprised if it isn't up to date.

Comment: Actually it's UEFI. The name BIOS is still used, wrongly, because tradition.

Comment: @ChanganAuto ok, so despite my computer being very new, you are saying I should update my UEFI, as well as update the firmware for my SSD, and then retry installing Ubuntu? Also, does the youtube link I mentioned look like a good way to update my UEFI? I just want to be very clear I understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: @oldfred you know of people who updated their SSD firmware and updated their UEFI to get their Ubuntu install to work properly? Have you also seen this happen even when their computer is very knew?

Comment: I didn't watch the video. Update using the method recommended by the manufacturer and please check for an update and if there's one apply it. If there isn't you can be sure there will be one very soon. Re: your questions to oldfred let me say that's yes to all and I concur.

Comment: Some new systems, still have an update available. And many SSDs also have update. I have updated my new Samsung NVMe drive with an ISO downloaded from Samsung. My systems now are 5 or 7 years old and are not getting UEFI updates anymore. Most UEFI have multiple ways to update UEFI. From inside Windows, from directly download of update file into a FAT32 formatted partition (either flash drive or internal) or a DOS type bootable flash drive. Many new systems also use fwupdate. If buying a new system for Linux I would only consider those on this list. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/

Comment: update: so I called Lexar support, and they said that their SSDs don't have firmware updates. also, apparently Linux commonly has compatibility issues with their SSDs. this makes a lot of sense given the reddit post I linked in my question... so I will likely get a different SSD to get this whole setup to work.

Comment: I was able to get Ubuntu 21.04 to work with my SSD. That is not the version I want though... does anyone know of an SSD that is known to work with Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Don't forget Ubuntu 18.04 is the 2018-April release of Ubuntu; so was your hardware created in 2017 so it was known by the kernel & software found in 18.04?  Newer hardware often needs newer software; yes enterprise grade hardware often ensures Linux kernel patches are ready at launch (when much of there sales will be to enterprise customers; ie. usually servers) but that doesn't apply to consumer grade gear. Re-spins of older releases only have kernel & graphic stack renewed; not installer etc (with boot only touched where security issues are discovered). A Server ISO using subiquity may help